# Cocoa - application/force-download and NSURLConnection

Tags: php, cocoa, nsurlconnection, mime

In my application, I have to deal with an unfortunate MIME-type, application/force-download. I do know for a fact that a NSURLConnection can be established to download a file if a direct link is given (e.x. http://blah.com/something.zip), but nowhere can I find any success/information on an URL like such http://blah.com/download.php?id=123 which would be a PHP file. Web browsers can certainly execute this function, but how would this be possible with the Cocoa library. Any suggestions/guidelines would be certainly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a delegate for your `NSURLConnection` object, and in that delegate implement this method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
```

From the `NSURLReponse` argument, you can obtain the MIME type and the suggested file name:

```
NSString* type = [response MIMEType];
NSString* fileName = [response suggestedFilename];
```

It's then up to you to write your app such that for MIME types of `application/download`, you take the `NSData` received via the delegate and save it to disk with the appropriate filename.

Comment: So essentially there is no difference on how the data is received?When I initiate the NSURLConnection with a NSURLRequest set to an URL like http://blah.com/download.php?id=123 it should be able to establish a connection and receive the data through - (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;

Comment: Absolutely, the MIME type is just a hint for the user agent for what to do with the content.